# Probability of two different groups of students passing an exam

Tags: probability, statistics

A group of $60$ students pass their exam with a probability of $0.3$. Another group of $70$ students pass their exam with a probability of $0.5$. What is the expected number of students who will pass their exams? What is the probability of one student passing her/his exam?

So far the only way to approach the problem I can think of is $0.3 \cdot 60 + 0.5 \cdot 70 = 53$ will pass their exams. Therefore, $\frac{53}{(60+70)} = 0.4$ is the probability of one student passing her/his exam. 
However, the groups have different number of people. I am not sure if this makes one of the group a more reliable prediction of the outcome.

Comment: As another approach, note that a randomly selected student has a $\frac {60}{130}$ chance of being from the first group, and a $\frac {70}{130}$ chance of being from the second.  Thus the probability that this randomly selected student passes is $\frac {60}{130}\times .3+\frac {70}{130}\times .5=.408$.  This is really the same as the calculation you did, but perhaps it is more intuitive.